# how to embed the sqlite-database-file in android app

Tags: android, sqlite

Someone guide me plzzzz. I have a basic android-sqlite-database app for doing CRUD operations. It works fine when I do operations on `/data/data/package-name/mydatabase.db`. But now I have to embed the database file into the app. I have put the *`.db`* file in `assets` folder and written this code. But facing continuous problems as described below.... My *DatabaseHandler* class is as follows....

```
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "com.example.database_abc/assets/contactsDB.db" ; 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsDB";
private  SQLiteDatabase myDatabase ;
private final Context myContext ;

public DatabaseHandler3(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context ;

}

public boolean checkDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null ;
    try{
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DATABASE_PATH , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }catch(SQLException ioex){
        throw new Error("Database Not Found..........................");
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false ;
}// End of checkDataBase()


public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH ;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

   }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2){

}
```

My `Logcat` is as follows..

```
12-13 17:24:29.244: E/SQLiteLog(5563): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-13 17:24:29.244: E/SQLiteLog(5563): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(//com.example.database_abc/assets/contactsDB.db3) - 
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563): Failed to open database 'com.example.database_abc/assets/contactsDB.db3'.
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at com.example.database_abc.DatabaseHandler3.checkDatabase(DatabaseHandler3.java:27)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at com.example.database_abc.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:55)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 17:24:29.384: E/SQLiteDatabase(5563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.384: D/AndroidRuntime(5563): Shutting down VM
12-13 17:24:29.394: W/dalvikvm(5563): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     ... 11 more
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Database Not Found..........................
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at com.example.database_abc.DatabaseHandler3.checkDatabase(DatabaseHandler3.java:29)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     at com.example.database_abc.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:55)
12-13 17:24:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(5563):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: why not just create the DB when your app starts, and include any default data in the scripts you're executing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're creating the database, but using something like the Firefox [SQLiteManager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to create, then pasting into the assets directory has always worked fine for me.  The other reason could be version incompatibilities, or something has simple as the extension (`db3` vs. `db` or `sqlite`).

Comment: I have previously created the database, perform the CRUD operations (when file was in "data/data/package-name/database/" directory. But I want to use the embedded database. So I pull the same file into assets and changed the code, but it did not work. It is the same file as that one.

Comment: Hm, then I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. "Embedded database", like, on the device? A database stored in another?

Comment: I just want to add database into my app means when I install it on android phone it will have its own database to store the data. If Im doing something wrong, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that I used to create my apps which use a read-only sqlite database:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

It gives all the code needed to move a database packaged in your asset folder to its final resting place in "/data/data/XX.XXX.XX/databases" location.

Also give this link a read if your database is large:

http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/

Comment: I have used this tutorial but it updates the  same .db file i.e. "data/data/packagename/databases/mydatabase.db". My assets/mydatabases.db file was not updating. Dear, has it worked well for read-only purpose???

Answer (score 0):

Donnot what's wrong with this, but i think you should better try this

> SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, factory);